# How to Make First Image Link to Post in Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

In category archives i use the_content read more to show image with a text. I want this image to link to a post. I have problems making it work because my first images in posts either are linking already to external site or they aren't.

I know of two ways to do it.
1. I delete first image from the_content and then use the_post_thumbnail().

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]\>/i", "", $content, 1);
} return $content;
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

It works. But it only strips image. I have a lot of posts that are also links. How to change this code so it removes first image with a link if it already exist? I tried adding this.

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a href[^>]\>/i", "", $content, 1);
```

But it's not good enough. It does strip link. But if image does not have a link it strips next link. Which is often the_content more link. I tried mixing a href and img within one preg_replace but can't make it work.

2. Second option would be simply changing/adding a href to image. For which i found this code.

   ```
   $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i","", $content, 1);<br>
   $old = '/(<img[^>]+\/>)/i';<br>
   $new = '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" title="'.esc_attr(get_the_title()).'">$1</a>';<br>
   $content = preg_replace($old, $new, $content, 1);
   ```

This one is good enough as well. But has the same issue as previous method. Because my images are both with a href and without.

Can you help me out with this? Also which method would be better to use. That is more lighweight.

Comment: So you want the external link in tact for the single page view, but change the link on the category view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to change the_content excerpt alone.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to make it work. Not sure if that's the right way to do it.
Here is the code.

```
if (!function_exists('image_to_post')) {
function image_to_post($content){
if (!is_singular()) {
$content = preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'), array('<img','/>'), $content);
$old = '/(<img[^>]+\/>)/i';
$new = '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" title="'.esc_attr(get_the_title()).'">$1</a>';
$content = preg_replace($old, $new, $content, 1);
}
return $content;}
add_filter('the_content', 'image_to_post');}
```